# Possible to disable button when onClicked is used?

Tags: android

It's easy to disable a button when I use listeners like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(btnSub);
button.setEnabled(false);
```

But when I use the onClick for the button in the XML file and just call a method in the main file, is it possible to reach that button an disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the xml layout to set the on-click function of your button, then you use something like this, right?:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="yourFunction"
    ... />
```

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick), it says, that you need to supply a function for this, what takes a `View` parameter.

So you need to implement `yourFunction` this way:

```
public void yourFunction(View view){...}
```

The `View`, what you get in that function, is the `Button` (or any other `View`) what you clicked.

So you just need to implement that function like this:

```
public void yourFunction(View view)
{
    view.setEnabled(false);
}
```

---

**EDIT**
If you give that `Button` an id with the following xml attribute:

```
android:id="@+id/my_button"
```

Then you can access that `View` (`Button`) from your `Activity` (or `Dialog`):

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_id);
```

and enable it:

```
myButton.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! It was this I was looking for: view.setEnabled(false);

Comment: Hmm, but what if I want to set the button back to TRUE when I press another button, then I guess I can't reach that view from another buttons View Method!?

Comment: OK, but then I need almost all the code to handle button like in the other way. Which way is the best? To use the onClick from the Layout or create listeners in java?

Comment: I never used the xml onClick, but i wouldn't say, that one is better that the other.